# Can't find WCF end points

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am trying to consume a wcf end point from a .Net class library project. I added the service references to my client project. The following is my client

```
        try
        {
            ServiceResult svcResult;                
            using (MyServiceClient myClient = new MyServiceClient())
            {
                svcResult = myClient.DoSomething(param1, param2);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

my app.config file looks like as follows

```html
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1234/MyWCFServices/MyService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService"
                contract="MyService.IMyService"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

But whenever I try to initialize my service client I get the following error

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyServices.IMyServices' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Even though the application adds the endpoint reference to app.config by default, I tried copying to Web.config(as suggested in most q&a forums) and running it my client still do not initialize and it still cannot find the end-point. What am I missing here?

Comment: what type of client are we talking about here? Console / WinForm / WPF / Web ?  I have a feeling that you put the config in the output folder of the class library project, but you should actually put it in the config file of the host using it. be it a console / desktop app / web app

Comment: @Menahem You are right. The client is in a class library(console app) which is then used as a reference by my web project. My app.config was inside a the class library project. I copied the service model end point definitions to my web project's config file and now it is working properly. Thanks for the observation. I should have thought of that from the beginning.

Comment: ill put it in an answer to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that you put the config in the output folder of the class library project, but you should actually put it in the config file of the host using it. be it a console / desktop app / web app.